# How to use symbols as a keyof type

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```
type Foo = keyof Set<string>
```

Here, `Foo` represents the type of all keys in the `Set` object, e.g. `add` or `delete`:

```
const a: Foo = 'add'; ✅
```

However, `Set` also has some well-known symbol properties:

```
const b: Foo = Symbol.iterator; ✅
```

However, in a `Pick` type, how can I reference a symbol key?

```
type A = Pick<Set<string>, 'add'> ✅
type B = Pick<Set<string>, Symbol.iterator> ❌
```

The second `Pick` does not work - "Symbol only refers to a type but is being used as a namespace here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Symbol.iterator` is a value, and you want the type.

```
type B = Pick<Set<string>, typeof Symbol.iterator>
```

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof Symbol.iterator` instead:

```
type pickedIterator = Pick<Set<string>, typeof Symbol.iterator> 
// { [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<string> }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBGCWDGBrCATAksCAnAhsA9llALxQAKCiAPAMoTBUDOwWsAdgOYB8ANFKJHwAzKDRABbAEb4ANgDpYmXASxcoAKAD0mqLoB6AfnVA)

Comment: Virtually identical answer, just a few seconds later. Gotta accept the other one. :)